# I can't set the screen resolution which is through HDMI to 1920X1080 for my laptop

Tags: resolution, nvidia, hdmi

monitor: ViewSonic VX2460h

GPU: Nvidia GT650M

NVIDIA Driver Version: 355.11

Output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3409 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
  1920x1080      59.9*+
HDMI-0 connected 1024x768+2385+203 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
  1024x768       60.0*+
 1360x768       60.0     59.8  
 1152x864       60.0  
 800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
 680x384        60.0     59.8  
 640x480        59.9  
 512x384        60.0  
 400x300        72.2  
 320x240        60.1
```

---

```
~$ cvt 1920 1080
-# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

---

```
~$ xrandr --newmode 1920x1080 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
 X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
 Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
 Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
 Serial number of failed request:  35
 Current serial number in output stream:  35
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that your `xrandr --newmode` syntax is incomplete (without the enclosing quotes).

Also, you should check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377944/114623) to make sure you're following the steps correctly, and you're giving xrandr the parameters it needs.

Finally, remember that in order to make xrandr modes permanent, you should create a script to add them at boot time.

Comment: I success for the newmode option, but the addmode is still the same.

Comment: ~$ sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "1920x1080_60.00"

Comment: X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Comment: Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)

Comment: Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)

Comment: Serial number of failed request:  35

Comment: Current serial number in output stream:  36

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BNGY7kW.png

Comment: Just a quick detail:  I see that you're issuing the xrandr command as root (with sudo).  I normally don't do it sudoing the command, but only `xrandr --newmode ... etc`.  Why don't you give it a go without sudo?

Comment: I tried, it was the same result.